# Can I post to a NetSuite Restlet from a chrome extension without going through a Suitelet first?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Can I post to a NetSuite Restlet from a chrome extension without going through a Suitelet first? What if I use token authentication? I don't want to expose credentials, but I would rather not go create the extra step of a Suitelet for performance reasons.

Comment: What is your use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No because of Cross-Origin Resource Sharing restrictions

I have one I use (locally only) but have to tell chrome to bypass security on mac. Other than that for a production application, not feasible. Use SSP

`open -a Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="" --disable-web-security`

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?
Why can’t you just do whatever processing in the suitelet?

If you need to do something with an elevated privilege level you can also set up a SSP application where a .ss file can be run as a role.

Comment: I'm trying to make a chrome extension that can do various tasks within NetSuite, including some which are not accessible to externally available suitelets. Not all API can be run from an externally available suitelet, I believe. Perhaps SSP application is the right way to go.